# Does ESP-CoAP library to implement CoAP protocol on ESP8266 still work?

Tags: esp8266, coap

I have tried using [ESP-CoAP](https://github.com/automote/ESP-CoAP) but the [coapclient.ino](https://github.com/automote/ESP-CoAP/blob/master/examples/coapclient/coapclient.ino) example does not work for me. The server in this example is 129.132.15.80. Is there any other server I can use to test my code? I have also tried coap.me but this code only accepts IP addresses. Are there any alternatives to this library that are regularly maintained?

Comment: I guess that library is fine. You just need to run `WiFi.hostByName (const char *aHostname, IPAddress &aResult)` first for the DNS resolution. Example: `printIPAddressOfHost` at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4949

Answer (score 2):

About the question for test-servers:

Many OS offers you a way to resolve a address as "coap.me" to their numeric address (e.g. unix nslookup coap.me => 134.102.218.18). The open source project [Eclipse/Californium](https://www.eclipse.org/californium/) offers a sandbox as well (nslookup  californium.eclipseprojects.io => 104.196.15.150). You may also try to run [Californium's Plugtest Server](https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/californium-releases/org/eclipse/californium/cf-plugtest-server/3.0.0-M1/cf-plugtest-server-3.0.0-M1.jar) locally (requires installed java).

In all cases, it's a good idea to get common with ip-capture tools as tcpdump or wireshark. A very first introduction may be [found here](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/wiki/Logs-and-IP-Capturing-%E2%80%90-How-To-Provide-The-Right-Information)

Answer (score 1):

About the question for maintained c-implementations:

[libcoap](https://libcoap.net/) is a very common one. But I don't know, if there is a "out of the box" ESP 32 port available.

Comment: The official SDK from Espressif, the ESP-IDF, supports libcoap. See https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components/coap and https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/coap_client